# python3.7 biopython, how to learn python3 and still use biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I'm very new to python and biopython, currently using a mac. I have python v2.7 and v3.7, and I would like to be learning with python3. Biopython only works on v2.7. Is it worth installing python V3.4 as well as these other 2 versions so I can learn python3 and use biopython? Or remove python3.7 and add 3.4? Even if I install python3.4 will biopython work if it was installed prior? Very confused biologist here.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/biopython/biopython), biopython works with up to Python3.6, and the document hasn't been updated for a year. It will probably work with Python 3.7 since there weren't many breaking changes

Comment: @user3080953 Officially Biopython won't support Python 3.7 until the next 1.73 version release. Biopython 1.72 (the current release as I write this) only supports up to Python 3.6. However, in practise is should be just fine, I know the devs have already fixed a number of Python 3.7 related issues for the 1.72 release https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/NEWS.rst#in-progress-not-yet-released-biopython-173

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check out this page: https://biopython.org/wiki/Download
You don't have to worry about biopython being bound to a specific version of python - you can use it with either v2.7 or v3.4/v3.5/v3.6. You can also have multiple version installed on your system but I recommend you to focus on digging deeper into one of them. Personally, I work now for several years with python3.x (at the moment 3.6) but I know a lot of people sticking to v2.7.

Having also a bioinformatics background, one thing that I can highly recommend you at the beginning of your journey is taking a course such as:
https://www.coursera.org/specializations/python
There is also a bunch of free tutorials on youtube - you will easily find one that fits your needs by searching for "python tutorial" or "python getting started".

Get yourself comfortable with the language, check out the basics such as data structures, databases, and data visualization. Check also some "python cheat sheets" - they can help you pick up the basic concepts of the language.
All the best and keep on coding!

Comment: Remember python2 will not be maintained any more in 2 years. Every new user should start with python3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - that's important to mention here!

Comment: Officially Python 3.7 will be supported in the next 1.73 Biopython release, see my comment under the question

Comment: Ok thanks very much for the help, I'm still a bit stuck sorry. I've downloaded python3.6.6 as well which I would like to learn python with. Following the instructions on the Biopython website, when in python try typing 'import Bio' to test if Biopython has downloaded properly. 

When I'm in python2.7, >>>'import Bio' doesn't give error messages, so I assume it is working.

But when I'm in Biopython3.6 or 3.7, >>>'import Bio' gives me the error message 'Module Not Found'. How can I fix it so Biopython can be run from python3.6?

Comment: It seems that you have downloaded Biopython for v2.7 but not for v3.6. Please always check which version of python you are using (on Linux terminal: which python; which pip) to pinpoint where your installation is going.

Answer (score 0):

From the biopython [installation document](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html):

> Biopython is designed to work with Python 2.5 to 2.7 inclusive. Python 2.7 is the final 2.x series release, and this would be our recommended version (assuming all other Python libraries you plan to use support it).
>
> Upgrading bug-fix releases (for example. 2.6.1 to 2.6.2) is incredibly easy and won’t require any re-installation of libraries.
>
> Upgrading between versions (e.g. 2.6 to 2.7) is more time consuming since you need to re-install all libraries you have added to python.
>
> As of Biopython 1.62 we officially support Python 3, specifically Python 3.3. Python 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2 will not be supported.

Also from the Biopython [website](https://biopython.org/wiki/Download):

> Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6 or PyPy, including the Python development header files like python.h

So biopython is inconsistent with their documentation.

I think your best option is to download either the latest version of Python 2 or 3 and see if it works.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for the help, I'm still a bit stuck sorry. I've downloaded python3.6.6 as well which I would like to learn python with. Following the instructions on the Biopython website, when in python try typing 'import Bio' to test if Biopython has downloaded properly. When I'm in python2.7, >>>'import Bio' doesn't give error messages, so I assume it is working. But when I'm in Biopython3.6 or 3.7, >>>'import Bio' gives me the error message 'Module Not Found'. How can I fix it so Biopython can be run from python3.6?

Comment: I'm replying to myself in case anyone else has the same problem, because I fixed it. I read that even though biopython is now on my mac in python2.7, I should re-install/re-download biopython again into python3.6. So I used this code in terminal: python3.6 -m pip install biopython AFTER I had also downloaded python3.6 and now I have biopython in 2.7 and 3.6, seperately.

Comment: Modules are downloaded per python version and not across every version. Something to keep in mind for the future.